# Jmeter how to generate threads as per number of columns in a csv file and each thread should pick up data from multiple rows of a specific columns

Tags: jmeter

[image: user configuration]

We are trying to establish no of threads depending on the number of columns present in a csv file, and each thread should pick up data from respective rows of those columns.
can someone help us out in achieving the same.

So from the attached screenshot we would want 6 threads to be established and thread1 should be posting data under user1 itself, thread2 from user2 and so on.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you can use CSV Data Set Config

How to set CSV Data Set Config?

1. Right Click on thread group
2. Navigate to Add > Config element
3. Click on CSV Data Set Config

Create one csv or txt file and CSV Data set config as per below attached screenshot.
[image]

Whenever you want to user your values, just provide `${user1}`, `${user2}` and so on.

For more details you can refer [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) from user manual.

Comment: how will you ensure that thread1 picks up data from 1st column and thread 2 picks up from 2nd column.

Comment: @vikranth you can verify from Request headers in listeners (View Results tree).